# Postgres range select between timestamps

Tags: postgresql

Having two timestamps, and result in minutes between them lets say 320 minutes I need to calculate full hours, lets say we have here 5h and 20 minutes and I need to insert 6 rows with minutes column (5 rows with 60 as minutes column and last one with 20 minutes)

What is best way to do it in Postgres, some loops or trying to select numbers with cte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1e0f55a3d783863ab459b8de511e8ad3)

```
WITH timestamps AS (
    SELECT '2019-01-07 03:30:00'::timestamp as ts1, '2019-01-07 08:50:00'::timestamp as ts2
)

SELECT 60 as minutes
FROM timestamps, generate_series(1, date_part('hour', ts2 - ts1)::int)

UNION ALL

SELECT date_part('minute', ts2 - ts1)::int
FROM timestamps
```

1. `date_part` extracts the `hour` (or `minute`) value from the timestamp difference.
2. with the `generate_series` function I am generating `n` rows with value `60` (`n = hours`)
3. Adding the remaining minutes with `UNION ALL`

---

**Edit: For more than 1 day:**

Instead of `date_part` use `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)` which gives you the difference in seconds.

```
WITH timestamps AS (
    SELECT '2019-01-06 03:30:00'::timestamp as ts1, '2019-01-07 08:50:00'::timestamp as ts2
)

SELECT 60 as minutes
FROM timestamps, generate_series(1, (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts2 - ts1) / 60 / 60)::int)

UNION ALL

SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts2 - ts1) / 60)::int % 60
FROM timestamps
```

1. Calculate the seconds into hours with `/ 60 / 60`
2. Calculate the remaining seconds with `/ 60 % 60` (first step gives you the minutes, the modulo operator `%` gives you the remaining minutes to hour)

Comment: this is great answer but the only problem is that if I chnage one timestamp to be other date like 2 days later then the difference is not calculated, the difference can't calculate something like total hours

Comment: @kosnkov added the solution for your case, updated fiddle